# Performance in the test is terrible, is it normal in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Here is a small test on the performance of Meteor 1.2.1.

performance.html

```
<head>
  <title>performance</title>
</head>

<body>
  <br><br>
  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Enter a keyword to search">
  </form>
  <br>
  {{> items}}
</body>

<template name="items">
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each items}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{first}}</td>
          <td>{{second}}</td>
          <td>{{third}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

performance.js

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection('items');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.items.helpers({
    items: function () {
      if (Session.get('input')) {
        var keyword = Session.get('input');
        var regex = new RegExp(keyword, "i");
        return Items.find({$or: [{first: regex}, {second: regex}, {third: regex}]});
      } else {
         return Items.find();
      }
    }
  });
  Template.body.events({
    "submit .search-form": function (events) {
      events.preventDefault();

      var input = events.target.keyword.value;
      Session.set('input', input);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    if (Items.find().count() < 5000) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5000; i++) {
        Items.insert({first: 'first_' + i, second: 'second_' + i, third: 'third_' + i, createdAt: new Date()});
      }
    }
  });
}
```

When I load or refresh the page Chrome's developer tools shows it took about 3 seconds. And if I input, e.g., 1 and hit enter, then it looks like no response for a few seconds but will show the result at last.
Maybe some suggestion said don't return all from collections, but really it's not a big data (5k docs, 3 simple fields) return, I also did the same thing by using Laravel 5 and MySQL, it works pretty smoothly, and I tried some query in Mongodb CLI also looks good, so what's the problem on the performance of Meteor?

Comment: It could be a few different things...rendering 5,000 items on the DOM can be a bit taxing after you hit submit. Can you confirm whether the rendering is taking the time or is it the Mongo regex query? Also, look in the network tab of chrome dev tools to see how big the requests are between the client and server for the xhr websocket chatter. It could be passing that full 5,000 record dataset from the server to the client every few seconds.

Comment: When the page refresh, it will have about 80 requests, one of them (not always that one) will takes most of the time. When hit to search, it looks can't get information from developer tools.

Comment: it is odd, that search do not generate any events in chrome network tab. same in firefox. Probably it is doing it all locally in minimongo.